# Notepad++ folding/collapsing hides everything?

Tags: notepad++, code-folding

I am running Windows 8.1 and just downloaded Notepad++ v6.8 to use in some HTML/PHP development.

The problem I am facing is with the little +/- (fold/collapse) signs on the left side of the IDE.

Normally when I click on one of the +/- icons to collapse a section, it only closes that level/section.

However now it is closing EVERYTHING under it too. (and not just that section/snippet of code, that matches grouping (open/closing tags)

Example illustrated below:

If I click the +/- next to any of the `<div> class="item">`s, it hides everything below it completely... even the footer include.

How can I fix this?  I tried looking into the fold/collapse levels stuff, but nothing has changed the results/behavior.

Is this a bug in a new version? I don't believe the install I have at my work computer works this way.

```
 <?
$pageTitle = 'Home Page';

include('_includes/header.php');

?>

<div id="slideContainer">
    <div class="item">
            <h2 class="itemTitle">Meet KO</h2>
            <div class="itemImage"><a href="/">
                <img alt="Meet KO" border="0" src="images/homepage/meet_ko.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="itemButton"><a href="/">
                <a href="/"><img src="images/homepage/learnMore_btn.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- vsmile -->
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="itemTitle">Try On A New Smile</h2>
            <div class="itemImage"><a href="/">
                <img alt="Try On A New Smile" border="0" src="images/homepage/mvb_icon.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="itemButton"><a href="/">
                <a href="/"><img src="images/homepage/learnMore_btn.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- getting started -->
        <div class="item">
            <h2 class="itemTitle">Getting Started</h2>
            <div class="itemImage"><a href="/">
                <img alt="Getting Started" border="0" src="images/homepage/ko_101.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="itemButton"><a href="/">
                <a href="/"><img src="images/homepage/learnMore_btn.jpg" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>


<div id="greyContainer">
    test text
</div>

<?

include('_includes/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: is this happening with other IDEs or notepad?

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with my copy of Notepad++, version 6.7.7, so it wasn't introduced just with 6.8.

Comment: Is there a setting or something to fix this? or set the correct (single level/element) closing behavior somehow?

Comment: bump....  so is this just a bug introduced in the latest versions?  I'm sure whatever version we have at work (which I'm sure if a bit older) did NOT have this odd behavior.

What good is 'code folding'  (or whatever you want to call it, 'collapsing') if it hides EVERYTHING else under the section you are trying to collapse?

More like HIDE everything behavior.  I'm hope some knowledgeable soul out there knows where to correct or change this ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your folding problems are due to the unmatched href links you have before some of the img elements.

```
<div class="itemButton"><a href="/">
            <a href="/"><img src="images/homepage/learnMore_btn.jpg" /></a>
```

My experience with this is usually the result of html syntax errors like improper nesting. I found this when I was including verbatim code between XMP tags that contained unmatched "tags" (not tags, but template parameters in C++). Notepad++ doesn't ignore text between XMP tags like browsers do.